# Why wifi file transfer does not work in my S5?

Tags: wi-fi, file-transfer, samsung-galaxy-s-5

I got my S5 yesterday. I have tried to use Wifi transfer pro and dooblou wifi file explorer to transfer file to my S5 external SD card, but they don't work. What I see is that my external SD does not show on the  Wifi transfer pro and dooblou wifi file explorer pages. Normally, I will see my SD card available space in their pages.

Please help

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I believe these kind of apps don't show for some reason your external SD card.
What I can suggest to you is:

1. Try another app like Airdroid. Maybe there it will work.
2. Somewhat of a workaround - transfer the file to the internal SD card and then use a file explorer (on your phone) to transfer it to the external SD card.